# ansible aws ecr login without using docker command

Tags: docker, ansible, amazon-ecr

I want to login in aws docker ecr registry using ansible

```
    # return  docker login -u AWS -p <token> 
   -name: dget docker command
    shell: "aws ecr get-login --region {{ aws_region }}"
    register: docker_login_command
    
   -name: docker login 
    shell: "{{docker_login_command.output}}"
```

this will required docker cli install in our machine.but we are using docker container to run ansible with share docker socket. is there way to not use docker cli for this?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, maybe easier, is to rely on `get-login-password` rather than `get-authorization-token`

For example, basing on instance profile :

```
- name: Get instance profile info
  amazon.aws.aws_caller_info:
  register: aws_info

- set_fact:
    ecr_registry_url: "{{ aws_info.account }}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

- name: Get ECR token
  shell: "aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1"
  register: ecr_token

- name: Log into ECR registry
  docker_login:
    registry_url: "{{ ecr_registry_url }}"
    debug: yes
    username: "AWS"
    password: "{{ ecr_token.stdout }}"
    reauthorize: yes
```

Answer (score 3):

try this. this work for me.

```
  - name: ecr docker get-authorization-token
    shell: "aws ecr get-authorization-token  \
    --profile {{ envsettings.infra.aws_profile }} --region {{ envsettings.infra.aws_region }}"
    register: ecr_command
  
  - set_fact:
      ecr_authorization_data: "{{ (ecr_command.stdout | from_json).authorizationData[0] }}"
  
  - set_fact:
      ecr_credentials: "{{ (ecr_authorization_data.authorizationToken | b64decode).split(':') }}"
  
  - name: docker_repository - Log into ECR registry and force re-authorization
    docker_login:
      registry_url: "{{ ecr_authorization_data.proxyEndpoint.rpartition('//')[2] }}"
      username: "{{ ecr_credentials[0] }}"
      password: "{{ ecr_credentials[1] }}"
      reauthorize: yes
```

it required docker pip python module. install before above code

```
  - name: install required packages for this role
    pip:
      state: present
      name: docker
      executable: /usr/bin/pip3
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
- name: "Teili e zaga"
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:    
   - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
```